# Rails 7 - Enum on unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mutation

I'm making a shopping cart, in the terminal I can create a Cart instance easily, in the GraphiQL, using a mutation, as well, but when I'm making the test for it to create a Cart with the mutation, it returns me this:

```
"Failure/Error: raise self::UnresolvedValueError.new(enum: self, value: value, context: ctx)
 Types::Enums::CartTypeEnum::UnresolvedValueError:
   `Cart.status` returned `"in_progress"` at `createCart.status`, but this isn't a valid value for `CartTypeEnum`. Update the field or resolver to return one of `CartTypeEnum`'s values instead."
```

this is the create_cart_spec.rb file:

```
describe Mutations::Cart::CreateCartMutation do
  it 'creates cart' do
    customer = create(:customer, :with_address_info_and_units)

    mutation_string = <<-GRAPHQL
        mutation($attributes: CreateCartInput!, $customerId: ID!) {
          createCart(attributes: $attributes, customerId: $customerId) {
            totalAmount
            status
          }
        }
    GRAPHQL

    cart_payload = {
      'status' => 'CLOSED',
      'totalAmount' => "123.12"
    }

    result = ApiSchema.execute(
      mutation_string,
      variables: {
        attributes: cart_payload,
        customerId: customer.id
      }
    )

    cart_result = result['data']['createCart']

    expect(cart_result.to_json).to eql(cart_payload)
  end
end
```

this is the crete_cart_mutation.rb file:

```
    module Mutations
      module Cart
        class CreateCartMutation < Mutations::BaseMutation
          description 'Mutation to create Cart'

          argument :attributes, Types::Cart::CreateCartInputType, required: true,
                                                                  description: 'Attributes to create Cart'
          type Types::CartType

          def resolve(attributes:, customer_id:)
            enums = {
              INPROGRESS: 0,
              CLOSED: 1,
              WAITINGPAYMENT: 2
            }
            cart_type = enums[attributes[:status].to_sym]
            ::Cart.create!(attributes.to_h.merge({ customer_id: customer_id, status: cart_type }))
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

this is the cart_type_enum.rb file:

```
module Types
  module Enums
    class CartTypeEnum < Types::BaseEnum
      description 'Which status is the Cart'
      value 'INPROGRESS', :in_progress
      value 'CLOSED', :closed
      value 'WAITINGPAYMENT', :waiting_payment
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: "Cart.status` returned `"in_progress"`", but your value is `:in_progress`. Maybe that's the error.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it returned "in_progress" but in cart_payload I sent "closed". Tried to put "in_progress" instead of :in_progress in the cart_tye_enum.rb, but then it returned "empty"